# XCOM: Enemy unknown - detached nations

Tags: xbox-360, xcom-enemy-unknown

When panic level reaches the top in XCOM-adherent nations, they choose to leave the program, as it is notified by the Council.

My question is: it is possible to have them re-enter the XCOM program again during the story?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you have mods, which I don't believe you can obtain in the Xbox version, nations that are lost due to terror/panic *are lost forever*. There is no way to get them back, outside of modding.